# Where can I find the lease rates for office and industrial space in my area (Sturgeon Bay, Wisconsin to be specific)?

Tags: data-request

I'm looking for a data source that shows me lease rates.  I know there are some on Costar and LoopNet, but I do not have a subscription and am hoping there is a free data source available.